# json_encode (PHP) returning a non-JSON object

Tags: php, json

I want to use json_encode on a PHP array that I have, then return it to an AJAX call.

Here is the php array called `$match_array`

```
Array ( [0] => 1966318353 [1] => 1962510086 [2] => 1962465781 [3] => 1962349187 [4] => 1962281400 [5] => 1962111347 [6] => 1962016291 [7] => 1961983582 [8] => 1961926702 [9] => 1961799894 )
```

Using json_encode on `$match_array` returns the following:

```
[1966318353,1962510086,1962465781,1962349187,1962281400,1962111347,1962016291,1961983582,1961926702,1961799894]
```

This gets interpreted by the parser as a non-json object. Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: `json_encode` will convert your array into a json string. For you to access that parse it in the client side.

Comment: What do you expect the string to look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag, try:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` interprets arrays with numbered key values as a JSON array which is a valid JSON string.  If you use something like `JSON.parse()`, it will give you back an array in JavaScript.  The above poster is correct if you are actually looking for an object type.  Using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT will force the array to be in object notation like `{'0': 1966318353 ... }`